# Google + Android API fails on some devices and runs on some

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-plus

code of my service-
It works on few devices and crashes (code 7 NW error on others)
Tested on Kitkat 4.4.2 HTC - ran
          5.1 - Meizu - ran
          5.1 - Moto g -ran
          4.4 - xiaomi - failed
          4.1 - sony - failed
I have wasted nights on this, can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
package gaurav.birthdays;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.People;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by gaurav on 24/7/16.
 */
public class GooglePlusService extends IntentService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ArrayList<String> listID;
    int tries = 0;

    public GooglePlusService() {
        super("GooglePlusService");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

       String ID = (String) intent.getStringExtra("Id");
        String[] userId = ID.split(",");
        listID = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(userId));
        System.out.println(listID);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if( mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("connecting");
        }

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("connected");

        }
      try {
            Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient,listID).setResultCallback(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(GooglePlusService.this, "No Contacts in Google plus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        System.out.println(peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode());
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());


        if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {

                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String bday = personBuffer.get(i).getBirthday();
                    if (bday != null) {
                        bday = procBday(bday);
                        String name = personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName();
                        String msg = "Happy Birthday!";


                        if (!dbHandler.exists(name, bday)) {
                            dbHandler.insertData(msg, name, bday, "");
                        }
                    }

                }


            } finally {
                Toast.makeText(GooglePlusService.this, "Import Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dbHandler.close();
                personBuffer.release();
            }
        } else {
            if(tries<2) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, listID).setResultCallback(this);
                tries++;
            }


        }
    }

    String procBday(String inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
        String[] parts = inp.split("-");
        String bday = parts[2] + "/" + parts[1];
        return bday;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("BYE");

    }


}
```

Gradle -APP

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gaurav.birthdays"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(project.property("MyApp.signing"))
            storePassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
            keyAlias project.property("MyApp.signing.alias")
            keyPassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.1'

}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I'd suggest migrating to google sign in. As the API is deprecated and it would crash on android m, if you don't have the run-time permission android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, the app would crash on it.

Comment: Would do that, any cure for my problem?